# Collapsing nodes if no other element is inbetween

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<doclist>
<text attribute="a">This is a <tag1>sentence</tag1> <tag1>with</tag1> a few            
<tag1>words</tag1>.</text>
<-- many more text nodes with none, one or several '<tag1>' in it -->
</doclist>
```

and i want to get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<doclist>
<text attribute="a">This is a <tag1>sentence with</tag1> a few <tag1>words</tag1>. 
</text>
<-- many more text nodes with none, one or several '<tag1>'s in it -->
</doclist>
```

I have tried doing it with a regex:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
<text>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/> <!-- templ. to copy attributes of text -->
<xsl:analyze-string select="." 
regex="&lt;tag1>(.+)&lt;tag1>&lt;tag1>(.+)&lt;/tag1>">
<!-- also tried . instead of &lt; -->
<xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:for-each select=".">
<tag1>
<xsl:value-of-select="regex-group(1)">
<xsl:text> <xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of-select="regex-group(2)">
</tag1>
</xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:non-matching-substring>
<xsl:for each select=".">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
</text>
</xsl:template>
```

But my output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<doclist>
<text attribute="a>This is a sentencewitha few words. 
</text>
<-- many more text nodes with none, one or several '<tag1>'s in it -->
</doclist>
```

My guess, what happens is that the matches arent found, as no`<tag1>`s appears in the result - but i dont understand why only the words surounded by the tag lose their whitespace... 
How can i correctly collapse `<tag1>`s that are direct neighbours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for-each-group` `group-adjacent` if you need to operate on nodes (mixed content of element nodes and text nodes), you can't use `analyze-string` to operate on element nodes.

So I think that

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::tag1 or self::text()[not(normalize-space())]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <tag1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </tag1>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text/tag1">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should do, that stylesheet, when applied with Saxon 9, transforms the input

```
<doclist>
<text attribute="a">This is a <tag1>sentence</tag1> <tag1>with</tag1> a few            
<tag1>words</tag1>.</text>
<!-- many more text nodes with none, one or several '<tag1>' in it -->
</doclist>
```

into the result

```
<doclist>
<text attribute="a">This is a <tag1>sentence with</tag1> a few
<tag1>words</tag1>.</text>
<!-- many more text nodes with none, one or several '<tag1>' in it -->
</doclist>
```

and I think the approach should work with more complex input samples. But please test yourself and report back, if there are problems then add more complex input samples to the question so that we have something to test with.

Comment: thx, i added the template that matches tag1 and used group-adjacent (didnt know about them). The output looks like the intended result. I am wondering though, why "or self::text()" is needed.  I looked at o'reillys xslt book, and tried it with "boolean(self::tag1)" as well, but that doesnt collapse the elements. Whats the difference between the two?   Also, i am curious why you used <xsl:copy> in place of the element. Is that a style convention?

Comment: In the XPath data model that XSLT operates on the input sequence `<tag1>sentence</tag1> <tag1>with</tag1>` results in a sequence of nodes made up on an element node, a text node with a single blank character and a second element node. And we want to group all three of them together, so that is why I used `xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::tag1 or self::text()[not(normalize-space())]`.

Comment: As for using `xsl:copy`, if you have `match="text"` you can as well create a `text` element node literally. But using `xsl:copy` allows you to treat several elements with the same template i.e. if you have other elements requiring the same treatment you can use `<xsl:template match="text | foo | bar"><xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group ...>...</xsl:for-each-group></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Very informative. About the group-adjacent, if i understand correctly, it does this: "Select ech node whichs adjacent nodes have the same tag as it has, `tag1`. Or select the text within these nodes and keep the spaces." But why is it "or"? Why not "and"?

Comment: It is difficult to explain the tree model of XSLT in a Stackoverflow comment but with the XML `<text>This is a<tag1>sentence</tag1> <tag1>with</tag1> a few words.</text>` the `text` element node has five child nodes: 1) A text node with the text `This is a`. 2) A `tag1` element node (which contains a text child node with the text `sentence`. 3) A text child node with the text ` ` (single space). 4) A `tag1` element child node (which has a text child node with the text `with`. 5) A text child node with the text ` a few words.`. The `for-each-group select="node()"` processes all child nodes.

Comment: We then need a condition in the `group-adjacent` to make sure we find adjacent `tag1` element nodes or adjacent `tag1` element nodes and white space text nodes. That is why `group-adjacent="self::tag1 or self::text()[not(normalize-space())]"` checks whether a node to be grouped is a `tag1` element node or a white space text node.

Comment: If you need to become familiar with XSLT 2.0's `for-each-group` then start with the examples in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples.